# When parsing nested JSON using Jackson, which method is the preferred approach: ArrayNode or TypeReference?

Tags: java, generics, jackson, jackson2, jackson-databind

I have to parse the following JSON. I have two solutions and I'm trying to decide which is the preferred approach.

```
{
    "created": true,
    "entries": [{
        "NewValue": "test1",
        "Operation": "ADD",
        "FieldIdentifier": "name",
        "FieldType": "AN",
        "FieldLength": 35,
        "OriginalValue": ""
    },
    {
        "NewValue": "test2",
        "Operation": "ADD",
        "FieldIdentifier": "age",
        "FieldType": "AN",
        "FieldLength": 35,
        "OriginalValue": "testOrig"
    }]
}
```

### Solution 1: Use readTree to get the JSON into a JsonNode object we can query, then convert into a list

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode jsonObject = mapper.readTree(form.getFieldList());
ArrayNode fieldListArray = (ArrayNode) jsonObject.get("fieldList");
if (fieldList != null) {
    FieldDefType[] listOfFieldDefs = mapper.convertValue(fieldList, FieldDefType[].class);
    if (listOfFieldDefs != null) {
        request.setFieldList(Arrays.asList(listOfFieldDefs));
    }
}
```

### Solution 2: Use TypeReference to map from JSON to POJO object and then retrieve my fields from there.

```
FieldListModel fieldListModel = new FieldListModel();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
fieldListModel = mapper.readValue(form.getFieldList(), new FieldListTypeReference());
request.setFieldList(fieldListModel.getEntries());

// At bottom of this class I have my named static inner class - Sonar scan requested this
static class FieldListTypeReference extends TypeReference<FieldListModel> {}
```

I'm leaning towards solution 1 as there is no need for a named static inner class and anecdotally I have heard on Stack Overflow that TypeReference is slow. The only issues with solution 1 I can think of is the need for more null checks and more lines of code.

Comment: That totally depends on the circumstances, and this is why both methods are supported. Typically, solution 1 would be used if the JSON schema is unknown or changes, otherwise, solution 2 may be better.

Comment: That is a criteria for making a decision that I did not think of. I just asked the team that created the JSON structure and the JSON schema will not change.

I will change the code back to Solution 2.